# In stock, freshly uploaded product showing out of stock on frontend - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, out-of-stock, vendor

I am using marketplace module but the products uploaded by vendors are showing 'Out of stock'. However, if I upload any product from backend it shows 'In stock'. I've tried this on all type of products i.e simple, virtual, bundle, configurable and downloadable products. If the product is uploaded from admin side it shows 'In Stock'. If the product is uploaded from vendor side it shows 'Out of Stock'.

I've checked the inventory to show out of stock, if and only if the QTY left is 0, but still facing the error. I've reindexed the data and flushed and cleared cache but still, nothing changed. I've also checked the product QTY and replace quantity by 100 (100 product in stock) but still, they are showing out of stock on the frontend.
Is there anyone who can help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: which module are you using ? mostly marketplace work in a way that if vendor uploads proudct from their account these are held for moderation / approval and show on site after these are approved by admin. so you need to check the extension or contact the extension developer

Comment: i am using medma market place module. and i have approved all products but when they display on frontend they are labeld as out of stock

Comment: then you should contact module developer to insvestigate thee issue, without looking code it won't be possible to help you out.